# fit_transform() with KneighborsClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, knn

Being novice to Machine Learning, I have been exploring background of regression and classification Algorithms.

I have been working on a Classification dataset from Kaggle using Logistic Regression & KNN. I noticed that KNeighborsClassifier doesn't have a fit_transform(). My understanding of fit & transform goes like this

fit():- fit uses the required formula and perform the calculation on feature variable of input data and fit this calculation

Transform():- Transform is used to change the data calculated with fit() function.

If this is the case & my understanding is correct , then can some help me explaining why KNeighborsClassifier doesn't have a fit_transform().

Thanks

Comment: `fit_transform` is for data transformation techniques, like scalers. When you train a model, whether it be KNN, SVM, RF, etc etc, you will have a `fit` command followed by either a `predict` or `predict_proba` command (depending on your use case). No model (that i know of) will have a `fit_transform` method.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.